Integrability of a fractional Sobolev function
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 2$ be a bounded domain and $0<s<1$ and $\alpha,q>1$. Assume that $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function such that $u\in W^{s,q}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$.
Here $W^{s,q}(\Omega)$ is the fractional Sobolev space defined by
$$
W^{s,q}(\Omega)=\left\{v:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}:v\in L^q(\Omega),\,\frac{v(x)-v(y)}{|x-y|^\frac{N+qs}{q}}\in L^q(\Omega\times\Omega)\right\}.
$$
The space $W^{s,q}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is defined analogously. The space $W_0^{s,q}(\Omega)$ is defined by
$$
W_{0}^{s,q}(\Omega)=\left\{v\in W^{s,q}(\mathbb{R}^n):v=0\text{ in }\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega\right\}.
$$
For any $k>0$, we define $T_k(u)=\min\{k,u\}$. Let $u\in W^{s,q}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ be such that for every $k>0$, we have $T_k(u)^{\frac{\alpha+1}{2}}\in W^{s,q}_{0}(\Omega)$. Then is $u\in L^1(\Omega)$?
I posted this question as a part of another question in Integrability of a Sobolev function
But have not get an answer there for the general question. So I posted this case separately here. Can someone please help me with this. Thanks a lot.
